# Orthogonal families of curves

Tags: plotting

I have a problem that requests that I plot two families of curves:

$$x^2+y^2=r^2\qquad\text{and}\qquad ax+by=0$$

I can get the first family with:

```
ContourPlot[x^2+y^2,{x,-3,3},{y,-3,3}]
```

Anyone have a good suggestion for superimposing the second family on the same plot?

Comment: Note that the second family of curves may be written `y/x = -a/b`.  Then you can ContourPlot y/x.  The numerics near the vertical lines gets finnicky, so you can equivalently plot `ArcTan[y/x]` or `ArcTan[y,x]` or `anyFunctionOfOneVariable[y/x]`.  As far as making it look nice in terms of super-imposing, I think other solutions here are good.

Answer (score 6):

```
s = Table[y - Tan@p x == 0, {p, 0, Pi, Pi/20}];
s1 = Table[y^2 + x^2 == r^2, {r, 0, 4, .3}]; 
ContourPlot[Evaluate@Join[s1, s], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You should change the first line to ``s = Table[Cos@p y - Sin@p x == 0, {p, 0, Pi, Pi/20}];`` this way you won't miss the ``x==0`` line

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps

```
ParametricPlot[r {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {r, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
 Mesh -> {9, 17}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or

```
ParametricPlot[r {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {r, 0, 2 Sqrt[2]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
 Mesh -> {Round[9 Sqrt[2]], 17},
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, u, v}, Abs[x] <= 2 && Abs[y] <= 2]]
```

or even just clip with `PlotRange` instead of `RegionFunction`.  It produces a cleaner boundary. (Edit: Added some styling.)

```
ParametricPlot[r {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {r, 0, 2 Sqrt[2]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
 Mesh -> {Round[9 Sqrt[2]], 31}, 
 MeshStyle -> (Directive[Thickness[0.005], Opacity[1], #] & /@ ColorData[97, "ColorList"]),
 BoundaryStyle -> (Directive[Thickness[0.005], Opacity[1], ColorData[97][2]]),
 PlotStyle -> None, Axes -> False, PlotRange -> 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Closer to OP approach:

```
ContourPlot[{
  x^2 + y^2 == Range[10], 
  x Range[-10, 10] + y Join[Range[0, 10], Range[9, 0, -1]] == 0}, 
{x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

Result:

[image]

With slight modification:

```
ContourPlot[{x^2 + y^2 == Range[1, 6, 0.5]^2, 
  x Range[-6, 6] + y Join[Range[0, 6], Range[5, 0, -1]] == 0}, 
{x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

[image]